# Parameters for hyperparameter grid search functions in tidymodels tuning

Tags: r, data-modeling, tidymodels

I’m using `{workflowsets}` from `{tidymodels}` for the first time, and I’m following along [chapter](https://www.tmwr.org/workflow-sets.html) in *Tidy Modeling with R*.

In the book, the authors use a fixed, regular grid hyperparameter search:

```
grid_results <-
   all_workflows %>%
    workflow_map(
        fn = "tune_grid",
        seed = 1503,
        resamples = concrete_folds,
        grid = 25, # See note below
        control = grid_ctrl
   )
```

Help for the `tune::tune_grid()` function specifies that *“[a]n integer denotes the number of candidate parameter sets to be created automatically.”*

While this has worked for me, I wanted to try a space-filling design, such as those created with `dials::grid_max_entropy`. However, this function (much like all grid-generating functions in `{tune}`) requires a *param* or *parameter set* object.

How can I extract parameters *en bloc* from a workflow set, seeing as how there is no `parameters` method for `workflowsets` (yet)?

Thanks!

Edit: added `fn` argument to `workflow_map` for clarity, even though it’s not present in the book (`tune_grid` is the default value for the arg).

Answer (score 1):

I'm quoting the answer of Max Kuhn in this GitHub [issue](https://github.com/tidymodels/workflowsets/issues/37)

> The best approach is to use option_add(). There is an example in the upcoming blog post that does this (but to define a custom parameter range for the grid). You could do:

```
wflow_set <- 
  wflow_set %>% 
  option_add(grid = some_grid, id = "some wflow_id")
```

Also, I found this [presentation](https://github.com/topepo/2021-LA-RUG) by Max Kuhn very useful. Namely slide 24 illustrates "Passing individual options to models". This is the YouTube link of the presentation (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2OfTEakSFXQ)